# python points to global installation even after virtualenv activation

Tags: python, virtualenv

It's a bit weird, I have activated the virtual environment python still points to the global installation.

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ source ~/virtualenv/bin/activate
(virtualenv)$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you need to check `/bin/activate`. Check the value for `VIRTUAL_ENV` and other hard coded environment variables.

Comment: How did you create virtualenv?

Comment: Thanks @BarunSharma and Eugene, I had actually moved the directory which resulted in this problem. I updated the VIRTUAL_ENV path and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Great. Can you add an answer in 1 or 2 lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to pointers from @Barun Sharma, I could fix this.

Initially I had created a virtual environment in the directory `~/projectname`. Later I decided to move it to under `~/virtualenv`. This would result in a stale path  `~/projectname` in $PATH variable. Updating VIRTUAL_ENV to the latest path in /bin/activate solved the problem.