# how to solve "bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links"

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

I am trying to install numpy in a virtual environment that I created. I used the following series of commands to create and activate and then installing a local version of numpy (all these after cd-ing into the project folder).

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

However, after the last command, I get this error:

```
bash: /home/fieldsofgold/Desktop/test/venv/bin/pip: /home/fieldsofgold/Desktop/test/venv/bin/python: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Could anyone please help me solve it and let me know what could be going wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox, and the python version is 2.7.6.

Comment: can u go inside venv and do pip, just to make sure

Comment: @Ja8zyjits getting the exact same error

Comment: The symbolic links sounds like a filesystem issue. Were you mucking around in /usr/bin using ln -s on python related stuff? source
[reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2iugkj/very_confused_about_python_dev_environments_and/)

Comment: before pip execute `which python` and show the output here

Comment: it gives : /usr/bin/python

Comment: you have a problem my friend....the virtual environment is not properly installed. it should be `/home/fieldsofgold/Desktop/test/venv/bin/python`

Comment: did u actually mess with the `ln -s` command??

Comment: nope, I didn't, not directly, I've been trying to workout installing numpy with openblas, so don't know if that might be somehow linked. What do you think could be going wrong with the installation? I used a simple `sudo pip install virtualenv`

Comment: If you have used some `ln` commands then kindly post them here. We may know what you have done, `sudo pip install virtualenv` is correct though. thats what i did. but then after using `source` command did u get `(venv)$` as your bash prompt?

Comment: yep, I did, the current prompt is like this: `(venv)fieldsofgold@fieldsofgold-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/test$`
Nope, I didn't use any `ln` commands in the terminal.

Comment: I just tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338187/python-points-to-global-installation-even-after-virtualenv-activation) solution to a similar question, and checked the value of the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable in venv/bin/activate, and it seems to be pointing to the correct environment: `VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/fieldsofgold/Desktop/test/venv"`

Comment: did u run the `pip` after that??

Comment: yes, but it gives the same error and `which python` also still points to the global python installation

Comment: ok after editing the VIRTUAL_ENV 
execute `deactivate`
then restart the virtual env with the `source` command

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't work. However, I just tried creating a new test folder, and created a new virtual environment inside, and now when I run the source command, `which python` points to the local installation. And numpy's installation is also currently progressing. So, it finally works! Thanks so much. I don't know what is going wrong with the other one if this new one is working.

Comment: happy to have helped you!!!

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue, and solved it simply by removing the old env file with `rm -rf env`. Then I created a new environment with `virtualenv env`, followed by installing the requirements, normally `pip install -r requirements.txt`, then I was able to run my app successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You may have python running in some other instance of terminal. Make sure to close all additional instances of terminals

Comment: That is completely irrelevant. Individual python interpreters can't effect other processes.

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue but I had a pycharm project with project-root/odoo/venv1    project-root/django/venv2 . Got bad interpreter error on 'pip install -r requirements.txt' in the console for venv2, so deleted and made a new venv2 - but ALSO stopped running venv1 (it was running in pycharm) and no more bad interpreter error

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to install Tensorflow by Virtualenv, I confronted this question too. I just removed the old env, then built a new env. It works.

When I type `which pip`, it returns `/Users/xiang/tensorflow/bin/pip`. Which is exactly the path in the new env I built.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurs 'cause time you start a new process, in my case virtual environment for django project one copy is made and when they becomes to many you get this error.
Just remove the old env and create a new environment.

Answer (score 0):

I can vaguely speculate that the reason for this is that you have a virtualenv pointing to itself. I can further vaguely speculate that this would happen if you attempt to create a virtualenv, but then somehow decide to do it again without running `deactivate`.  Then you have `python` in the virtualenv pointing back to ... `python` in (effectively) the same virtualenv by a symbolic link.

Since this is speculative, I hope someone who actually has this problem can confirm or deny that this is what happened.

Anyway, if this is the case, the other answers here saying remove the env and start over are basically correct, but remember to `deactivate` first.

Answer (score 0):

I had this. In my case I am not sure what happened but my python2 had been replaced by a link so I had:

```
ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 <me> staff    7 Oct 23 14:04 python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 <me> staff    6 Nov  6 14:28 python2 -> python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 <me> staff    7 Oct 23 14:04 python2.7 -> python2
```

The middle link is wrong, this is a circual reference, it should be the executable (had another venv to look at already). I deleted python2 and copied the actual file (in my case /bin/python2.7) to there:

```
rm python2
cp /bin/python2.7 python2
ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 <me> staff    7 Oct 23 14:04 python -> python2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 <me> staff 7216 Dec  6 14:57 python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 <me> staff    7 Oct 23 14:04 python2.7 -> python2
```

(NOTE: I can't speak for every distro. you'll need to work out your own version. Try this:

```
ls -l `which python`
```

and if that is a link follow it until you get to the actual executable. For me is was /bin/python -> python2 -> python2.7. Ergo I copied /bin/python2.7)