# How to fix circular links?

Tags: python, virtualenv

**UPDATE:**
I tried

```
ls -lrt `find ./ -follow -type l`
```

And found these as my circular links:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 matthew  staff  9 Apr 30 18:01 .//eatLowCarbon/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 matthew   staff  6 Apr 30 18:03 .//eatLowCarbon/bin/python2.7 -> python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 matthew   staff  6 Apr 30 18:03 .//eatLowCarbon/bin/python2 -> python
```

What can I do to remove them?

---

I tried to install virtualnev, but am getting [the same error to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696119/how-to-solve-bad-interpreter-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links).

My commands for [installing virtualnev](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/):

```
pip install virtualenv
cd eatLowCarbon
virtualenv eatLowCarbon
source eatLowCarbon/bin/activate
```

However, when I tried to install html5lib, I got this error:

```
/Users/matthew/eatLowCarbon/eatLowCarbon/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

When I do `which python`, it tells me '/usr/local/bin/python`, which according to the SO I linked to, means that virtualenv was not installed properly.

Comment: you made a virtualenv called ``eatLowCarbon``, but are sourcing from ``my_project``?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to solve "bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696119/how-to-solve-bad-interpreter-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links)

Comment: @Grimmy I changed it! typo

Comment: @Grimmy and that is the thread that I tagged in my post. my question is how to edit VIRTUAL_ENV, which they mention but don't describe how to do. I need assistance for how to actually edit VIRTUAL_ENV

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't really have an answer other than just closing the terminal.. delete all the envs you might have there including hidden ones (starting with dot) and open a fresh terminal trying again.