# Why can't I pip install on virtualenv? What is happening here?

Tags: python, bash, pip, installation, virtualenv

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/src/flask_class$ source env/bin/activate
(env) vagrant@vagrant:~/src/flask_class$ ls
app        config.pyc  manage.py   README.md        tests
config.py  env         migrations  requirments.txt
(env) vagrant@vagrant:~/src/flask_class$ pip install -r 
requirments.txt 
-bash: /home/vagrant/src/flask_class/env/bin/pip: 
/home/vagrant/src/flask_class/env/bin/python2: bad interpreter: Too 
many levels of symbolic links
(env) vagrant@vagrant:~/src/flask_class$
```

I don't understand what is happening with the file path and why it says bad interpreter, and too many levels of symbolic links, help. I can't run any of my projects currently and it's been days.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696119/how-to-solve-bad-interpreter-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links

Comment: @zabusa you can mark the question as duplicate by flagging it...