# how to solve jupyter notebook problem showing "bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links"?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04

When I type jupyter notebook in my terminal (ubuntu 18.04) it shows:

```
bash: /home/evil/anaconda3/bin/jupyter: /home/evil/anaconda3/bin/jupyter: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I have tried the solution given here: 
[how to solve "bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696119/how-to-solve-bad-interpreter-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links) but that didn't help.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /home/evil/anaconda3/bin/jupyter`?

Comment: the output
-rwxrwxr-x 1 evil evil 239 Mar 24 12:00 /home/evil/anaconda3/bin/jupyter

Comment: Now check the shebang inside the file (first line) and do the same for the interpreter there. If it is not presented as absolute path your might need to use `which …` on it.